# How to reject an email using mailgun?

Tags: email, cloudmailin, mailgun

Does anyone know how to reject an email received through mailgun (mailgun.com)? 
As a comparison, a similar service, cloudmailin allow you to return a status code of 404 or 403 to reject an email, and the sender of that email will receive a delivery failure notice. 
I am trying the same with mailgun, however, mailgun will attemp to redeliver with longer and longer interval once it receive the 404 or 403 status code.

What I have tried:
Mailgun documentation doesn't say anything about this.
Mailgun support is not responding to my emails.

If I got an answer from mailgun I will post it here as an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app could return 406 code to mailgun to stop retrying. We added that feature recently and haven't yet updated our documentation regarding that.

Comment: I notice recently when I return 406, the sender doesn't get a bounce message at all.

Comment: However, this does not seem to send a delivery failure notice (NDR) back to the original sender.